# how to make a html button semi transparent

Tags: html, button

im using the following

```
<input type="button" value="360P" onClick="53p('<?=$a?>gh_456_dd<?=$b?>')" style="background:transparent;color:#A8A8A8;font-weight:bold" name="button2">
```

is there anyway i can make the button Background RED but have it a bit transparent? i don't want the background solid as it takes away from the video but full transparent is hard to read anyway to choose a background color but have it a little see thru? 
any help or advice would be GREAT thanks guys!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply this to your background

```
rgba(255,0,0,0.5)
```